# Python: Why the console show me an error take arguments?

Tags: python, class, subclass

i'm a new programmer python, and i'm practicing a object programming.. and i have the next code:

```
class Vehiculos():

def __int__(self, marca1, modelo1):

    self.marca = marca1
    self.modelo = modelo1
    self.enmarcha = False
    self.acelera = False
    self.frena = False

def arrancar(self):

    self.enmarcha = True

def acelerar(self):

    self.acelera = True

def frenar(self):

    self.frena = True

def estado(self):

    print("La marca es:", self.marca1)
    print("El modelo es: ", self.modelo1)

class Moto(Vehiculos):
pass

mimoto = Moto("BMW", "CR1")
mimoto.estado()
```

and the console show me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "herencia_new_file.py", line 31, in <module>
mimoto = Moto("BMW", "CR1")
TypeError: Moto() takes no arguments
```

soo, i'm wondering what's wrong? because i saw in a course that code and the teacher works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a typo in `__int__` (should be `__init__`), also, you have another mistake in the `estado` method, you're accessing the attributes `marca1` and `modelo1` when you should access `marca` and `modelo`:

```
class Vehiculos():
  def __init__(self, marca1, modelo1):
    self.marca = marca1
    self.modelo = modelo1
    self.enmarcha = False
    self.acelera = False
    self.frena = False

  def arrancar(self):
    self.enmarcha = True

  def acelerar(self):
    self.acelera = True

  def frenar(self):
    self.frena = True

  def estado(self):
    print("La marca es:", self.marca)
    print("El modelo es: ", self.modelo)

class Moto(Vehiculos):
  pass

mimoto = Moto("BMW", "CR1")
mimoto.estado()
"""
La marca es: BMW
El modelo es:  CR1
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you originally wrote `__int__` instead of `__init__`.

In Python, we use `__init__()` as a constructor function when creating an object of a class. This function allows you to pass arguments to a class object. If you misspell the `__init__` function, you will encounter the error: `TypeError: object() takes no arguments.`

To solve this error, you need to ensure that you spell the `__init__` function with two underscores on either side of `init`, and you use correct indentation throughout your program.